# How can I make the radio boxes in html look like checkboxes and make them have x's when checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I want to make a form that has radio boxes that look like checkboxes. Furthermore I want them to have the glyphcon x's when checked. I tried several solutions for this including:

```
        input[type="radio"] {
            -webkit-appearance: checkbox; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -moz-appearance: checkbox;    /* Firefox */
            -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
        }
```

When I used this solution it made checkboxes with line across the checkbox that would disappear after one was checked and they were hovered over.

I also tried the solutions offered here: [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)
and they did not seem to work.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? People have intuitive expectations that map appearances to behavior. Things that seem innocuous to developers can often be really confusing to users.

Comment: Why should you use a radio instead of check?

Comment: @majidrazvi Yes I am sure I want to do this.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I want to use a radio instead of a check because I only want to allow the user to select one choice.

Comment: So why not build a javascript function that will only allow one selection? You could modify this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626277/make-only-2-checkboxes-checked-per-form/41626424#41626424 to do that.

Comment: but you can use check in the same way :|

Comment: Maybe something like this https://jsfiddle.net/9xvoh6h9/ this is using `jQuery` by the way. If you read the previous solution you will understand how that works. the only thing I have changed is the selector to remove all checked boxes within that form and then re-selected the last selected box giving you the same thing as a radio button. That function can also be used on multiple forms.

Comment: Hi, For CSS only solution, take a look at this library https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution would make things easier for you.

I have written this function so you can use it on as many check boxes as you want. The only requirement it to give them a class of `radio` and the same name for that group of options.

> **jQuery Solution**

```js
$('input[type=checkbox][class=radio]').on('change', function(e) {
  var Group = this.name;
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=' + Group + '][class=radio]').prop('checked', false);
  this.checked = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Eyes</h4>
Blue <input type="checkbox" name="eyes" class="radio"> 
Green <input type="checkbox" name="eyes" class="radio"> 
Brown <input type="checkbox" name="eyes" class="radio">
<h4>Hair</h4>
Black <input type="checkbox" name="hair" class="radio"> 
Brown <input type="checkbox" name="hair" class="radio"> 
Ginger <input type="checkbox" name="hair" class="radio">
```

> **Pure Javascript Solution**

```js
var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('radio');
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
  checks[i].addEventListener('change', radios, false);
}

function radios() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=" + this.name + "]");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].checked = false
  }
  this.checked = true;
}
```

```html
<h4>Eyes</h4>
Blue <input type="checkbox" name="eyes" class="radio"> 
Green <input type="checkbox" name="eyes" class="radio"> 
Brown <input type="checkbox" name="eyes" class="radio">
<h4>Hair</h4>
Black <input type="checkbox" name="hair" class="radio"> 
Brown <input type="checkbox" name="hair" class="radio"> 
Ginger <input type="checkbox" name="hair" class="radio">
```

If you have any question about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!