# get value of checkbox and perform computation

Tags: javascript, php

I have 3 checkboxes:

```
<label><input type="checkbox">100%</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">50%</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">25%</label>
```

and one textbox1 that have fix value

```
<?php 
    $sampleValue= "200.35"
?>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sampleOfsample"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $sampleValue ?>" >
```

If the checkbox check one it will get the % the value of `$sampleValue` and it will echo the amount at the same textbox.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks...

Comment: `value = "<?php echo $sampleValue" >` => `value = "<?php echo $sampleValue ?>"/>` you haven't close out of `php` and missing a double quote to close the value attribute.

Comment: i didn't see that one. thanks

Comment: What if one selects more than one checkbox at a time?? Use radiobutton instead

Comment: you mean to say anyone one of three check box one is checked then you want to show text box value otherwise none right?

Comment: yes sir, if any check box is check it will perform computation and i will display the value in the same text box @Rits

Comment: iv'e been thinking radio tho instead check box @YashParekh

Comment: what computation?? and above two code snippet is in the same file?

Comment: if the user select one checkbox it will compute the % of $sampleValue = "200.35". @Rits

Comment: i thought you got your answer right? @gene ian Gutierrez

Comment: @geneianGutierrez If you want to limit the client from only being able to select one option with a `checkbox` you might find [**one of my previous answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989096/how-can-i-make-the-radio-boxes-in-html-look-like-checkboxes-and-make-them-have-x/42989382#42989382) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I think you use only PHP without JavaScript and need to transfer data from one file to another. I assume you have form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="fileName.php">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name='checkBoxOne'>100%</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name='checkBoxTwo'>50%</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name='checkBoxThree'>25%</label>
    <input type="Submit" value ="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Now what happens on the back-end side (fileName.php)

```
$checkBoxOne = $_POST["checkBoxOne"]
$checkBoxTwo = $_POST["checkBoxTwo"]
$checkBoxThree = $_POST["checkBoxThree"]
```

You check which one is filled and input into field`s value like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sampleOfsample"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $sampleValue ?>" >
```

Also, I would suggest to use "Select" element and not checkBox, because it will always send "one" value and you won't have to check each checkbox values.