# Disable form fieldsets unless certain inputs are checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I make checkbox and radio inputs disabled per fieldset and then sequentially enabled after certain inputs are selected?

> For example: Initially, all fieldsets but the first one are disabled.
>   After user selects input in the first fieldset, second one is enabled.
>   And so on and so forth.

Related to that, how can I display the calculated value only after radio input in the second fieldset is checked?

```js
const calculator = document.querySelector("form");

const occasionPricing = {
 party: 20,
 birthday: 25,
 anniversary: 50,
 wedding: 100
}

const sizeIndexes = {
 six: 1,
 eight: 1.5,
 ten: 2,
 twelve: 2.5
}

const extrasPricing = {
 candles: 5,
 inscription: 10,
 decoration: 25,
 special: 50
}

function cakes() { 
 var cakes = Array.from(calculator.elements["cake"]).slice(0, 3);
 var raphael = calculator.elements["raphael"];

 function isChecked(checkbox) {
  return checkbox.checked;
 }

 var count = cakes.filter(isChecked).length;
 if (count) {
  count = count * 0.5 + 0.5;
  if (raphael.checked) {
   count += 1;
  }
  return count;
 }
 return 0;
}

function occasion() {
 var occasionCost = 0;
 var occasion = calculator.elements["occasion"];

 for (var i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
  if (occasion[i].checked) {
   occasionCost = occasionPricing[occasion[i].value];
   break;
  }
 }
 return occasionCost;
}

function size() {
 var sizeIndex = 1;
 var size = calculator.elements["size"];

 for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
  if (size[i].checked) {
   sizeIndex = sizeIndexes[size[i].value];
   break;
  }
 }
 return sizeIndex;
}

function extras() {
 var extrasCost = 0;
 const extras = calculator.elements["extras"];

 for (var i = 0; i < extras.length; i++) {
  if (extras[i].checked) {
   extrasCost = extrasCost + extrasPricing[extras[i].value];
  }
 }
 return extrasCost;
}

function calculateTotal() {
 var totalCost = cakes() * occasion() * size() + extras();
 calculator.total.value = "$" + totalCost;
}
```

```html
<form>

<fieldset>
 <legend>Select Cakes</legend>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="leonardo" onclick="calculateTotal()">Leonardo</label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="donatello" onclick="calculateTotal()">Donatello</label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="michelangelo" onclick="calculateTotal()">Michelangelo</label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="raphael" onclick="calculateTotal()">Raphael</label>
 <p>If you select more than one cake, the other cakes are discounted 50%.</p>
 <p><small>Does not apply to Raphael.</small></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
 <legend>Choose Occasion</legend>
 <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="party" onclick="calculateTotal()" required>Party</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="birthday" onclick="calculateTotal()">Birthday</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="anniversary" onclick="calculateTotal()">Anniversary</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="wedding" onclick="calculateTotal()">Wedding</label><br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
 <legend>Choose Size</legend>
 <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="six" onclick="calculateTotal()" required>6-inch</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="eight" onclick="calculateTotal()">8-inch</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="ten" onclick="calculateTotal()">10-inch</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="twelve" onclick="calculateTotal()">12-inch</label><br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
 <legend>Select Extras</legend>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="candles" onclick="calculateTotal()">Candles</label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="inscription" onclick="calculateTotal()">Inscription</label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="decoration" onclick="calculateTotal()">Decoration</label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="special" onclick="calculateTotal()">Special Frosting & Icing</label>
</fieldset>

<input type="text" name="total">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calculateTotal()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an onchange event listener on fieldset and trigger a function that would enable the next fieldset. Check out the working snippet

```js
const calculator = document.querySelector("form");

const occasionPricing = {
  party: 20,
  birthday: 25,
  anniversary: 50,
  wedding: 100
}

const sizeIndexes = {
  six: 1,
  eight: 1.5,
  ten: 2,
  twelve: 2.5
}

const extrasPricing = {
  candles: 5,
  inscription: 10,
  decoration: 25,
  special: 50
}

function cakes() {
  var cakes = Array.from(calculator.elements["cake"]).slice(0, 3);
  var raphael = calculator.elements["raphael"];

  function isChecked(checkbox) {
    return checkbox.checked;
  }

  var count = cakes.filter(isChecked).length;
  if (count) {
    count = count * 0.5 + 0.5;
    if (raphael.checked) {
      count += 1;
    }
    return count;
  }
  return 0;
}

function occasion() {
  var occasionCost = 0;
  var occasion = calculator.elements["occasion"];

  for (var i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
    if (occasion[i].checked) {
      occasionCost = occasionPricing[occasion[i].value];
      break;
    }
  }
  return occasionCost;
}

function size() {
  var sizeIndex = 1;
  var size = calculator.elements["size"];

  for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
    if (size[i].checked) {
      sizeIndex = sizeIndexes[size[i].value];
      break;
    }
  }
  return sizeIndex;
}

function extras() {
  var extrasCost = 0;
  const extras = calculator.elements["extras"];

  for (var i = 0; i < extras.length; i++) {
    if (extras[i].checked) {
      extrasCost = extrasCost + extrasPricing[extras[i].value];
    }
  }
  return extrasCost;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var totalCost = cakes() * occasion() * size() + extras();
  calculator.total.value = "$" + totalCost;
}

function enableFieldset(element, event) {
  
  if (event.currentTarget.id == 'cakes') {
    var checked = false;
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("cake");
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checked = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (checked) {
      document.getElementById(element).disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(element).disabled = true;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(element).disabled = false;
  }


}
```

```html
<form>

  <fieldset id="cakes" onchange="enableFieldset('occasion',event)">
    <legend>Select Cakes</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="leonardo">Leonardo</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="donatello">Donatello</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="michelangelo">Michelangelo</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="raphael">Raphael</label>
    <p>If you select more than one cake, the other cakes are discounted 50%.</p>
    <p><small>Does not apply to Raphael.</small></p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="occasion" onchange="enableFieldset('size', event)" disabled>
    <legend>Choose Occasion</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="party" onclick="calculateTotal()" required>Party</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="birthday" onclick="calculateTotal()">Birthday</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="anniversary" onclick="calculateTotal()">Anniversary</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="wedding" onclick="calculateTotal()">Wedding</label><br>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="size" onchange="enableFieldset('extras', event)" disabled>
    <legend>Choose Size</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="six" onclick="calculateTotal()" required>6-inch</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="eight" onclick="calculateTotal()">8-inch</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="ten" onclick="calculateTotal()">10-inch</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="twelve" onclick="calculateTotal()">12-inch</label><br>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="extras" disabled>
    <legend>Select Extras</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="candles" onclick="calculateTotal()">Candles</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="inscription" onclick="calculateTotal()">Inscription</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="decoration" onclick="calculateTotal()">Decoration</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="special" onclick="calculateTotal()">Special Frosting & Icing</label>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="text" name="total">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calculateTotal()">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And how would you display the calculated value only after input in the second fieldset is checked?

Comment: Have modified the snippet. Check it out! Or now if I think of it, just remove calculate cost on cakes.

Comment: Cake multiplier in the first fieldset then isn’t used for calculation.

Comment: Great answer @cdoshi but one minor issue.... If you check and then uncheck something from **Cakes** you can still continue enabling the rest of the form. I believe the OP is wanting to use this to ensure the required options are selected (Client-side validation). I am sure you can make a minor change to your existing answer to fix this "If this is what the expectations are"

Comment: Yes you are right @NewToJS. Ideally the first fieldset should have been a radio button like other fieldsets instead of checkbox. This will ensure that at least one option is selected.

Comment: I agree, @NewToJS.

Comment: I did plan on submitting a solution but since this is a great start I didn't see much point so I thought I would share my input to try help you improve your post.

Comment: @NewToJS I have edited my post and switched from checkbox to radio. This will ensure that one option is always selected.

Comment: @cdoshi Well maybe you can make some use from one of my previous answers.... [**How can I make the radio boxes...**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989096/how-can-i-make-the-radio-boxes-in-html-look-like-checkboxes-and-make-them-have-x/42989382#42989382)

Comment: But checkboxes in the first fieldset are required so customers can order multiple cakes and get a discount :)

Comment: Ohh I see. My bad!!

Comment: @Boletrone added extra logic to handle in case all cakes are unselected again. I think you can take it up from here :)